# How can I get the reason for an invalid form with symfony 1.4?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I'm novice people for symfony. I wrote a code for form submission.

```
public function executeEdit(sfWebRequest $request)
    {
        $userId = $request->getParameter('id');
        $this->user = sfGuardUserTable::getUserById($userId);
        $this->form = new editOwnerForm($this->user);
        $this->paymentForm = new profilePaymentInfoForm($this->user->getPaymentInformation());

        if ($request->getMethod() == sfWebRequest::POST) {
            $this->form->bind($request->getParameter($this->form->getName()));
            if ($this->form->isValid()) {
                $this->form->save(); 
                $this->message = 'Successfully updated owner details';                               
            } else {
                var_dump($this->form->renderGlobalErrors()); die;
            }
        }
    }
```

Always my form is not valid. (always run else part of form valid) But i cant find the reason. `var_dump($this->form->renderGlobalErrors());` dont give any message. How can i fix it.?

Comment: Have you opened *_dev.php and checked if any errors are present in your developer toolbar?

Comment: I already use dev.php. It not give any error or reason. I also check log file. it also not display reason for this issue.

Comment: disable csfr token for testing

Comment: `renderGlobalErrors()` will only show errors not assigned to fields. You might have a problem with one of the fields. In the debug toolbar, in the `view` section you can find your form and see what the error is. Also, as @DelPedro suggests, try adding `$this->disableLocalCSRFProtection();` to your form's `configure()` function.

Answer (score 5):

You need to find the error from the form submission...

The debug bar's view section should show up in orange and highlight any errors in the form - just click 'view' then the highlighted form field.

If not, you could try changing your catch block to something like this for debugging:

```
foreach ($this->form as $key => $field) {
  $message = $field->renderError();
  if ($message) echo 'Error with field ', $key, ':', $message;
}
```

Not including the CSRF field is a common problem - have you included a call to $form->renderHiddenFields() in your form partial?

Comment: This works but you have an error in your "echo" line. Instead of "," it should be ".".

Comment: No, it should be "," :)  When concatenating things to output directly using echo it's much more efficient to use commas than periods.

Comment: No problem! Basically it's more efficient because each part gets echoed out instead of PHP internally concatenating the strings (moving things around and using memory) before outputting the whole thing.